# Git plugin not working in jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I tried to integrate git with Jenkins. In the process I installed git-client and git plugins. 
But unable to build using git.

Git not installed in Jenkins host server, we don't have root access and admins not allowed to install using root due to security reasons.

Is there any alternate to resolve this issue? 
We already installed dependency git plugins.

Comment: Is your question, 'can I pull from git without having git installed?' If so, I think the answer is probably 'no', otherwise, you might need to edit your question to make it a bit clearer what you're asking.

Comment: But we installed git plugins? is there no meaning for it.  Even we haven't installed SVN & CVS, we just installed plugins only.

Comment: The plugins allow Jenkins to work with git, but you need to have git installed for them to interact with.

Comment: could any one clear out the issue?